# ¿Cómo saber el tamaño del iterador o índice dentro de un arreglo?

Tags: java, array, bucles, iteradores

Print "Hola a todos."

---

public class Ejercicio4 {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Se aceptaran"
            + " solo números pares.");

    System.out.print("Digite el tamaño del arreglo: ");
    int tam = entrada.nextInt();
    int num[] = new int[tam];

    //Verificar si el número es IMPAR
    if (tam%2 != 0) {
        System.out.println("El bucle no se puede inicializar. El número"
                + " "+tam+ " es impar.");
    }else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Verificado!");

        for (int i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
            System.out.print((i+1) + ". Digite un número: ");
            num[i] = entrada.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.println("\nMostrando resultados...\n");

        for (int i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("*****************");
            System.out.println("Posición N:"+(i+1) + "| Contiene: " + num[i]);
            System.out.println("Posición N."+(num.length-i) + "| Contiene: " + num[num.length-i])
        }
        System.out.println("*****************");
    }
}
```

---

Yo quiero que me muestre por pantalla lo siguiente:

---

Posición N1. 1
Posición N10. 10

Posición N2. 2
Posición N9. 9

Posición N3. 3
Posición N8. 8

Posición N4. 4
Posición N7. 7

Posición N5. 5
Posición N6. 6

---

Claro que este ejercicio, podría ser más fácil, si no le pidiera al usuario llenar el arreglo.

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
int menor = 0;
int mayor = num.length - 1;


while (menor <= mayor) { // menor igual porque puede ser 0
   System.out.println("Posición N:"+(menor + 1) + "| Contiene: " + num[menor]);
   System.out.println("Posición N:"+(mayor + 1) + "| Contiene: " + num[mayor]);
   menor++;
   mayor--;
}
```